# Python statistically choose word from dictionary using list

Tags: python, list, dictionary, statistics, nlp

This goal is given a dictionary of potential words that have integer values assigned to each, the code is to create a separate list that adds the index and the value and then generate a random number. Then I go from that random number into the list and pick the first value larger than it. Then I return the word that the cumulative value corresponds to.

```
i = 0
cumulative = []
for self.nGramCounts in candidates:
    cumulative.append(candidates[i] + i)
    i += 1
x = random.randrange(0, 10)
print x #show x value 
for cumulative in cumulative[x:]:
    if cumulative[x] in cumulative:
        print candidates[x]
    else:
        x = x + 1
```

Here's an example of an input dictionary:

```
{'the': 2, 'quick': 1, 'brown': 1}
```

Comment: what is the expected output?

Comment: the key that the cumulative number (index + value) corresponds to

Comment: `for self.nGramCounts in candidates:` is a bit confusing; why are you assigning (over and over) the items in `candidates` to the instance attribute `self.nGramCounts` then you don't even use it in the loop suite?  What happens when you run this code?

Comment: You have dictionary of type (String -> Integer) as input. You have to generate a random number, then go through your dictionary and pick up a string of which value is bigger than the generated number. Finally you append your global list with the string. Am I right?

Comment: @BatyrkhanSaduanov the generated number is supposed to be the start from a list of numbers that is equal to the index of the dictionary plus the value of the key

Comment: `...equal to the index of the dictionary...` - dictionaries do not have indices, they have keys and values.

Comment: @wwii yeah that's what the + i is for, by index I just mean the relative position within the dictionary

Comment: okay, you generate an index, then you go to your dictionary and pick a value of element of such index. Then you sum up your index and value to create new index. Using that new index, you want to get the string from dicitonary?

Comment: Also, is your dictionary should be sorted by values?

Comment: @BatyrkhanSaduanov yup that’s exactly it, and no the dictionary isn’t necessarily sorted.

Comment: @BatyrkhanSaduanov I think it might be better to just add the cumulative value as a second value for each key but I don’t know how to do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a solution, however to maintain order of your dictionary, items should be appended one by one. In such exact order, items will be stored in OrderedDict object.

```
from collections import OrderedDict
import random

ordered_dict = OrderedDict()
ordered_dict['the'] = 2
ordered_dict['quick'] = 1
ordered_dict['brown'] = 1

generated_index = random.randrange(0, 3)
new_index = ordered_dict.values()[generated_index] + generated_index

resulting_string = ordered_dict.keys()[new_index]
print resulting_string
```

There is possibility that your new index will be out of bounds. Please think about how to handle such situation.